# Chrome is showing incomplete or wrong cert info

Tags: google-chrome, apache-http-server, ssl, certificate

We've got a webserver (Apache) at work that is using https for our webpage. The thing is that everytime I enter this page from chrome I get:

NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

I created the certificate and added it to the apache server config following the instructions of this webpage:

https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/392099-creating-self-signed-ssl-certificates-for-apache-on-linux

Now what I've tried to do is add the certificate in chrome by going to Certificate Manager and in the tab your certificates add the server.crt that I generated. This does not work as it asks for a password (I used the same passphrase as the procedure) and it says its corrupt. What I have managed to to do is added to the Authorities tab. I import the certificate and I get an entry showing a folder with my company's name and my own name. I edit the option and mark the checkbox "Trust this certificate for identifying websites".

I then restart chrome and the error persists. If I click in the x'ed lock (next to the site address) I see the cert details stuff like the company is not shown (which I filled out). So I figure this has to do with the problem.

Also, I added the certificate for an Authority. I also think I'm missing a step in which I say that the Authority (me) trusts the sites certificate.

Can anyone point me to what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT: It was pointed out to me that it is important to clarify that the Operating System is Debian.

Comment: Until you fully import the certificate you Chrome won't trust it.

Comment: Can you tell how do I do that? I have tried every option in Certificate Manager I could think of and/or find in the web and I can't get it to do it.

Comment: Have you tried using the browser to export the certificate.  You can use the "Copy to File" then import the file into the Trusted Certificate Store for the user and optionally for the machine.  If that doesn't work then how you created the certificate is likely suspect.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to try this. I know how to Export the certificate from the browser (just to be clear There is NO "Copy To File" Button. Only an "Export" Button). I create a file. How do I the Imported to the Trusted Certificate Store? I can't find an option for this in the Certificate Manager

Comment: You have to have rights to add the certificate to the Certificate Manager.  You can simply drag and drop the certificate into the Trusted Certificate Store, be sure you add both the certificate you created and the CA used to create the certificate ( if either are not already trusted this is a must ).

Comment: I sincerely think we are talking about two different things. For starters you reference Trusted Certificate Store as it should be written somewhere like so. I have not read it in anywhere in the certificate manager. I do not know what permissions I need but I am the root user if I want. Should I execute chrome as root?? Lastly dragging the saved certificate file to chrome only opens it in a new tab as text and does nothing else. I do not believe certificates can be added in this way. In case it matters I'm using Debian, not Windows.

Comment: So the client machine is using Debian?  How you specifically add the two certificates, I will leave that up to you, information about what operating system your using is something that should be in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppress Google Chrome's "Your Connection is Not Private" for specific Address?](http://superuser.com/questions/960850/suppress-google-chromes-your-connection-is-not-private-for-specific-address)

Answer (score 0):

As per [@Ramhound comment](https://superuser.com/questions/944256/chrome-is-showing-incomplete-or-wrong-cert-info#comment1285747_944256):

Until you fully import the certificate you Chrome won't trust it.

Have you tried using the browser to export the certificate? You can use the "*Copy to File*" then import the file into the Trusted Certificate Store for the user and optionally for the machine. If that doesn't work then how you created the certificate is likely suspect.

Make sure you have to have rights to add the certificate to the Certificate Manager. You can simply drag and drop the certificate into the Trusted Certificate Store, be sure you add both the certificate you created and the CA used to create the certificate  (if either are not already trusted this is a must).